# Factory Implementation in Java

Tags: java, python, oop, design-patterns, factory

After a few years of coding in python, I recently moved to Java for a project.
While working with Python, I had a pretty implementation for a factory.

```py
# file abstract_product.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class AbstractProduct(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something():
        pass
```

```py
# file product_factory.py
from abstract_product import AbstractProduct

class ProductFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self._creators = {}
    
    def get(self, product_name) -> Product:
        if product_name not in self._creators:
            raise ValueError('No valid implementation !')
        return self._creators[product_name]()
    
    def register(self, product_name, product):
        self._creators[product_name] = product

product_factory = ProductFactory()
```

```py
# file product1.py
from abstract_product import AbstractProduct
from product_factory import product_factory

class Product1(AbstractProduct):
    def do_something():
        # does something
        pass

product_factory.register('product1', Product1)
```

Now the advantage would be, that if I had a new Implementation for
Product, all I had to do was

```py
# file product2.py
from abstract_product import AbstractProduct
from product_factory import product_factory

class Product2(AbstractProduct):
    def do_something():
        # does something
        pass

product_factory.register('product2', Product2)
```

The advantages of the above approach were:

- I had my factory as a singleton. Defining the variable in module ensured that.
- Registering a new Product, included no changes to the existing code.
- No dirty if else ladder has to be set up any where!
- The new implementation registered to the factory in their own module. SO CLEAN :D :D

All the client code needed to know was the `product_factory` from above and the string parameter based on which the client would get some implementation of `Product`.

However, now with Java, I am thinking what can I do, to get close to the simplicity and extensibility that the above approach had !

### Note:

Please also suggest some other approach that you might have come across for an extensible factory that might even be better than the above !

Comment: There are OOP principles that can achieve what you need. Try looking into delegation etc

Answer (score 0):

This is how I like to do it (taken another class example),

```
public class MyFactory {
    private Map<String, MyInterface> factoryMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public MyFactory(List<MyInterface> listOfObjectsImplementingMyInterface) {
        for (MyInterface myInterface : listOfObjectsImplementingMyInterface) {
//Get the class annotation value, use it as map's key
            String strategyKey = myInterface.getClass().getAnnotationsByType(Component.class)[0].value();
            factoryMap.put(strategy, myInterface);
            
        }
    }

// To get an instantiation from factory
    public MyInterface getFromFactory(String strategyKey) {
        return factoryMap.get(strategyKey);
    }
}
```

The above example is a snippet from a spring f/w project, and with this method you can utilise the spring annotations to populate the factory rather than using messy if/else/switch blocks. The above method can be extended to other cases as well with custom annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Your python code can be quite easily translated to Java, and it doesn't look *too* "foreign".

```
// could even be an interface
abstract class Product {
  // ...
  abstract void doSomething();
}

final class ProductFactory {
  // not strictly a singleton, to allow you to create multiple factories
  // your python code allows this too

  private static ProductFactory instance = new ProductFactory();

  public static ProductFactory getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  private HashMap<String, Supplier<? extends Product>> creators = new HashMap<>();

  public void register(String productName, Supplier<? extends Product> creator) {
    creators.put(productName, creator);
  }

  public Product get(String productName) {
    Supplier<? extends Product> creator = creators.get(productName);
    if (creator == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No valid implementation !");
    }
    return creator.get();
  }
}

class Product1 extends Product {

  @Override
  void doSomething() {

  }
}
```

Example of registering and getting a product:

```java
ProductFactory.getInstance().register("product1", Product1::new);
System.out.println(ProductFactory.getInstance().get("product1"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only one thing that I still see as a catch is that, somewhere in the application code, you still need to register, once a new implementation is added. Now what should that component be ? With the python implementation, there wasn't really any need for a separate component! You could just do it right below the new implementation! And if I do define a new component, should I now go around and define one such component for all the factories in my application ?

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam I see what you mean. You’d normally put these register calls in a separate class, or the `main` method, or the factory class’s constructor, depending on your situation. Java isn’t meant to be like Python, sometimes the code can’t and shouldn’t be directly translated. If you want to be real fancy, I think you can annotate all your products with a custom annotation, and in the factory, find all the classes in the class path that has that annotation. That would involve reflection, and probably isn’t as fast as this...

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, the register calls in your python code would only run if you *import* product1.py and product2.py somewhere, right? Otherwise python doesn’t know about those files (?) Where is that “somewhere”? @RohitashwaNigam

Comment: You are right :) In the ```__init__.py``` of this subpackage, is where I would do them !

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam so the answer to the question of “where would I define such a component to put all the register calls” is:  you would move those Java register calls to a static `init` method in an `Init` class. Each time you add a new product, add a new register call in the method, similar to how you add a `import` to your init.py. Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, a *strict* conversion from your Python code into Java would be the snippet from below. Show this should feel more familiar to you.

For a simple application, you could make your Factory use `static` or use the Singleton design pattern to ensure a single instance.

If you are using some frameworks, is quite likely that it offers an alternative that requires less coding though and better testability.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// AbstractProduct may better be an 'interface' even
abstract class AbstractProduct {
    abstract void doSomething();
}

class Product1 extends AbstractProduct {
    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm Product ONE (1)");
    }
}

class Product2 extends AbstractProduct {
    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm Product TWO (2)");
    }
}

class ProductFactory {
    private final Map<String, Class<? extends AbstractProduct>> creators;

    ProductFactory() {
        this.creators = new HashMap<>();
    }

    AbstractProduct get(String productName) {
        if (!creators.containsKey(productName)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid implementation !");// <-- better define or use a specific exception
        }
        try {
            return creators.get(productName).newInstance(); // <-- Class.newInstance is deprecated since Java9, check docs for replacement
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // <-- deal with it properly
        }
    }

    void register(String productName, Class<? extends AbstractProduct> productClass) {
        creators.put(productName, productClass);
    }
}

public class PythonFactoryThing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductFactory productFactory = new ProductFactory();
        productFactory.register("product1", Product1.class);
        productFactory.register("product2", Product2.class);

        productFactory.get("product1").doSomething();
        productFactory.get("product2").doSomething();
        productFactory.get("product3").doSomething(); // <-- throws exception
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT**: if you don't want a separate place/file to register, you could use a static initialisation block (some Database drivers do that).

You'd have to adapt the above code like this:

Make a singleton out of your Factory:

```java
    private ProductFactory() {}// private constructor so nobody else cana instantiate it
    
    public static final ProductFactory INSTANCE = new ProductFactory();
```

And make each class do something like this:

```java
class Product2 extends AbstractProduct {

    static {
        ProductFactory.INSTANCE.register("product2", Product2.class);
    }

    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm Product TWO (2)");
    }
}
```

But for that to work you would also need to explicitly load the classes you want to have registered. Either by using them some place before using the Factory, or by calling:

```java
Class.forName("Product1");
```

Since the class loader only loads the classes that are explicitly needed. Which I suppose would be equivalent in Python to importing the file in your script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only one thing that I still see as a catch is that, somewhere in the application code, you still need to register, once a new implementation is added. Now what should that component be ? With the python implementation, there wasn't really any need for a separate component! You could just do it right below the new implementation!
And if I do define a new component, should I now go around and define one such component for all the factories in my application ?

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam, I edited the answer with some extra information as a reply to your comment.